# GET parameters not detected on freindly URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this line on my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^page$ index.php?page=page [L]
RewriteRule ^page\/$ index.php?page=page [L]
```

When i go to `http://localhost/page` work well, but when i add GET parameters for example:

```
http://localhost/page?cat=1&cat2=2&status=on
```

Nothing detected.

Even when i print everything:

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

I have only the rewrited parameter shown:

```
Array ( [page] => page )
```

Any clarification and solution to solve it ?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: `[L,QSA]` : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: Resolved yes, thank you.